# find using wholename

Tags: bash, find

Why does this invocation of find:

```
find . -wholename "./path/somewhere/*.py"
```

Take a lot longer than

```
find ./path/somewhere -wholename "*.py"
```

Is it because the first invocation will traverse the entire tree, and for each entry (regardless of where it is in the directory tree), it will do a patternmatch with wholename, whereas the second alternative traverses only the subtree matching the first parameter to find?

Comment: you answered it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you hit the nail on the head. This is why using `-prune` where possible can make a `find` command much faster.